# Calender View for Custom list used in Template

Tags: site-template, display-template

I have created a site template which contains number of custom views of the Custom list .
With in that i have calenderview for the list .

when i am using this web template to create a subsite, i am able to get some of the custom views but unable to get the calender view of the customList.
giving me Error that: List doesnot exist.
[image]

Colored webpart is holding the calenderview of the Projects List.

Comment: Are you able to change that bottom web part to a different view? What happens?

Comment: Yes.Even when i click on the Projects[2] ,it open the projects List.

Comment: Instead of using a web part, see if you can go straight to the list and add a SharePoint view of type Calendar. What happens?